# Stuttering Trackpoint and Imprecise Touchpad Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Thinkpad T440p

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

I got this Thinkpad T440p and it has issues with the trackpoint and touchpad.

The trackpoint has a stuttery motion and get's really annoying to use. Still has precision for small/slow motion though.

The touchpad becomes insensitive to motion if you move the mouse slow enough, then suddenly jumps to where it's suppose to be if you keep moving. It will do this constantly. It's absolutely impossible to be precise with this thing, only good for large movements.

Both these issues happen on every distro I try. I've also tried installing the 3 button touchpad upgrade for the T440p, and replacing the trackpoint nib with the concave one. I've also replaced the keyboard to no avail. This is getting to be an expensive laptop.

The only place left to try is troubleshooting Linux, but I don't even know where to begin. May I get some help please?

Answer (score 0):

Libinput ships a [purpose-built command to diagnose and address](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-jitter.html) issues with initially discarding small movement and later deciding to jump anyway:

```
# start by dumping currently active configuration
sudo libinput measure fuzz
```

Note that Ubuntu already ships Thinkpad-specific configuration (which may or may not be appropriate) in `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d`. Note further that Ubuntu in version 22.04 still supports the option of running a full-blown `X.org` server, so before logging into a desktop session use the session selection to verify you are logging into a native *Wayland* session: the newer design seeking to succeed most of the formers legacy.